# python retry with tenacity, disable `wait` for unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-tenacity

I am using the [tenacity](https://github.com/jd/tenacity) library to use its `@retry` decorator.

I am using this to make a function which makes a HTTP-request "repeat" multiple times in case of failure.

Here is a simple code snippet:

```
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(7), wait=wait_random_exponential(multiplier=1, max=60))
def func():
   ...
   requests.post(...)
```

The function uses the tenacity `wait`-argument to wait some time in between calls.

The function together with the `@retry`-decorator seems to work fine.

But I also have a unit-test which checks that the function gets called indeed 7 times in case of a failure. This test takes a lot of time because of this `wait` in beetween tries.

Is it possible to somehow disable the wait-time only in the unit-test?

Comment: I really know nothing about tenacy, but you might define the time as a local variable and replace its value in the test for wait=0

Answer (score 24):

The solution came from the maintainer of tenacity himself in this Github issue: https://github.com/jd/tenacity/issues/106

You can simply change the wait function temporarily for your unit test:

```
from tenacity import wait_none

func.retry.wait = wait_none()
```

Comment: How do we mock the stop value here?

Comment: Also, if you're using stop_after_delay (which depends on time), you can replace it with `func.retry.stop = stop_after_attempt(3)` (pick a suitable number for 3)

Answer (score 6):

After reading [the thread in tenacity repo](https://github.com/jd/tenacity/issues/106) (thanks @DanEEStar for starting it!), I came up with the following code:

```py
@retry(
    stop=stop_after_delay(20.0),
    wait=wait_incrementing(
        start=0,
        increment=0.25,
    ),
    retry=retry_if_exception_type(SomeExpectedException),
    reraise=True,
)
def func() -> None:
    raise SomeExpectedException()


def test_func_should_retry(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch) -> None:
    # Use monkeypatch to patch retry behavior.
    # It will automatically revert patches when test finishes.
    # Also, it doesn't create nested blocks as `unittest.mock.patch` does.

    # Originally, it was `stop_after_delay` but the test could be
    # unreasonably slow this way. After all, I don't care so much
    # about which policy is applied exactly in this test.
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        func.retry, "stop", stop_after_attempt(3)
    )

    # Disable pauses between retries.
    monkeypatch.setattr(func.retry, "wait", wait_none())

    with pytest.raises(SomeExpectedException):
        func()

    # Ensure that there were retries.
    stats: Dict[str, Any] = func.retry.statistics
    assert "attempt_number" in stats
    assert stats["attempt_number"] == 3
```

I use `pytest`-specific features in this test. Probably, it could be useful as an example for someone, at least for future me.

Comment: I don't know if this has changed since this was written, but I had to `with pytest.raises(tenacity.RetryError, match="OriginalExceptionClass")`, not `raises.(OriginalExceptionClass)`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to discussion [here](https://github.com/jd/tenacity/issues/106), I found an elegant way to do this based on code from [@steveb](https://github.com/steveb):

```
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, wait_exponential


@retry(reraise=True, stop=stop_after_attempt(5), wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=1, min=4, max=10))
def do_something_flaky(succeed):
    print('Doing something flaky')
    if not succeed:
        print('Failed!')
        raise Exception('Failed!')
```

And tests:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock, skip
from main import do_something_flaky


class TestFlakyRetry(TestCase):
    def test_succeeds_instantly(self):
        try:
            do_something_flaky(True)
        except Exception:
            self.fail('Flaky function should not have failed.')

    def test_raises_exception_immediately_with_direct_mocking(self):
        do_something_flaky.retry.sleep = mock.Mock()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            do_something_flaky(False)

    def test_raises_exception_immediately_with_indirect_mocking(self):
        with mock.patch('main.do_something_flaky.retry.sleep'):
            with self.assertRaises(Exception):
                do_something_flaky(False)

    @skip('Takes way too long to run!')
    def test_raises_exception_after_full_retry_period(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            do_something_flaky(False)
```

Answer (score 2):

mock the base class wait func with:

```
mock.patch('tenacity.BaseRetrying.wait', side_effect=lambda *args, **kwargs: 0)
```

it always not wait

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module to mock some elements of tentacity library. 
In your case all decorators you use are classes e.g. `retry` is a decorator class defined [here](https://github.com/jd/tenacity/blob/master/tenacity/retry.py). So it might be little bit tricky, but I think trying to

```
mock.patch('tentacity.wait.wait_random_exponential.__call__', ...)
```

may help.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to override the `retry` function of the `retry` attribute and while that sounds obvious, if you are playing with this for the first time it doesn't look right but it is.

```
sut.my_func.retry.retry = retry_if_not_result(lambda x: True)
```

Thanks to the others for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `tenacity.nap.time` in conftest.py in the root folder of unit test.

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def tenacity_wait(mocker):
    mocker.patch('tenacity.nap.time')
```